# How can I check if a Footer has been added to a listview?

Tags: android

I have a ListView to which i have added a footer.  What call can I make on the list view to determine if a given footer is currently added to the listview?

```
  listView.findViewById(errorFooterid) ?
```

there does not seem to be a method

```
 view.containsView(viewReference)
```

Checking if an existing view is contained by another seems like a basic operation, but I don't know if there is a reliable way to check this in android.

Why does the SDK not support a clear and simple way to check for this?  Even findByView(R.id.viewId) and null check is not very elegant way to do boolean check.

Answer (score 18):

If you had only one footer and want to know it's added or not, you would try to use

```
public int getFooterViewsCount ()
Since: API Level 1

Returns the number of footer views in the list. Footer views are special views at the bottom of the list that should not be recycled during a layout.
Returns

    The number of footer views, 0 in the default implementation.
```

So if it return 0, your `listview` doesn't have footer

```
yourListView.getFooterViewsCount();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can find out the number of footer views by using the following code

```
listView.getFooterViewsCount();
```

If it returns 0, There is no footer views present.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in an activity class then just use [findViewById(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29). If the method returns null then you can assume that the footer has not been added.

If this is a fragment class, then you can store the View that you return in your onCreateView() method as a data member of your fragment class.  Then it works the same way, except you will call findViewById() on the View that you saved.

```
LinearLayout footer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(footerId);
if (footer == null)
{
    //add the footer
}
else
{
    //Update the footer
}
```

Comment: Well I don't know.  What if there are two ListViews in the activity? Sometimes an id is not supplied in the footer layout, but a reference or the id is in the layout, but the layout is inflated once for each list.